Why mass unpublish script doesn't work?
I try to execute the following script
for (Knowledge__kav article: [SELECT IsMasterLanguage, KnowledgeArticleId, Language FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online']) {
    if (article.IsMasterLanguage) {
        KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle(article.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
    } else {
        KbManagement.PublishingService.editPublishedTranslation(article.Id, article.Language, true);
    }
    
}

to mass unpublish articles, and it fails with an error
Line: 37, Column: 1
System.HandledException: You can't perform this action. Be sure the action is valid for the current state of the article, and that you have permission to perform it.



Looks like there are some hidden undocumented limits and we must process at most 50 records at a time
for (Knowledge__kav article: [SELECT IsMasterLanguage, KnowledgeArticleId, Language FROM Knowledge__kav WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' LIMIT 50]) {
    if (article.IsMasterLanguage) {
        KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle(article.KnowledgeArticleId, true);
    } else {
        KbManagement.PublishingService.editPublishedTranslation(article.Id, article.Language, true);
    }
    
}

if we use 51, it would fail with the same error

As per this helpful article,

Custom lookup field to knowledge that's populated with an article translation prevents publishing

If there is a custom lookup field to the knowledge article version object, attempting to publish a translation referenced or populated in
the lookup may result in the error:
You can't perform this action. Be sure the action is valid for the current stat of the article, and that you have permission to
perform it.

This is known to occur when an article with a master version and a translation are both published and when the custom lookup field to
Knowledge is populated with the translated version of the knowledge
article. Edit of the master article and selecting to re-publish as the
same version will cause the translation draft to result in the error
above when attempting to publish.

Workaround to resolve the error condition on attempting to publish the translation:



Publish the master article as a new version or

Clear the lookup field that contains the reference to the translated knowledge article version.




I think this is not my case
